# "Invalid sequence" in Maple

Tags: math-software, maple

I tried to define a procedure in Maple as follows. removeAnElementInList:=proc(i, l)  local r, j;     r:=[];  for j from 1 to lengthOfList(l) do  (  if(j<>i) then   r:=append(r, l[j])  end if  )   end do;    return(r);  end proc;

But Maple returns an error: invalid sequence (at "then"). But I don't know where is the problem. I checked the codes for half an hour but didn't find the problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now its correct

> removeAnElementInList:=proc(i, l) local r, j; r:=[]; for j from 1 to
>   lengthOfList(l) do  if (j<>i) then r:=append(r, l[j]) end if  end do;
>   return(r); end proc;

Comment: thank you very much. Yes, your code works. But where are the differences between the old and new codes?

Comment: I see the difference. It seems that we need to use if () but not if()?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that way more simply, as well as way more efficiently, via

```
removeAnElementInList := proc(i, l) remove(j -> evalb(j = i), l) end proc;
```

Comment: It can be further simplified to **remove(\`=\`, l, i)**.

Comment: Wasn't the original question about a proc that would remove the i'th entry of the list. That's not the same as your code (and Carl's first comment's code) which removes instances of parameter i from the list. If I am interpreting the goal correctly then a terser and more efficient way would be the commonplace `proc(i,l) subsop(i=NULL,l); end proc`.

Comment: Also, if I interpreted correctly then it's understandable that one might be thrown by the inefficiency of the original code. Even `proc(i, l) [op(l[1..i-1]),op(l[i+1..nops(l)])]; end proc` or `proc(i, l) [seq(l[k],k=1..i-1),seq(l[k],k=i+1..nops(l))]; end proc` would be bearable. One can only wonder whether `append` and `lengthOfList` also use loops to build...

Comment: Yes, I see my mistake now. The original code is comparing loop indices rather than elements.